# Quick create Model Class from existing SQL Table

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF Code First in a project with an existing Database, all works well and so far I have been creating the class for each table manually (as they have been very small) but getting to the larger tables I can only assume there must be a better way to 'import' or 'convert' the tables fields into a class somehow.  Had a search around and can't really find what I'm looking for.

To clarify I want to keep it Code First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) contains [reverse engineer feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: It wouldn't install for me because I have an Express product

Comment: In such case you will probably have to write your classes manually because Microsoft strategy is: Productivity tools cost money.